# How to set a cookie for another domain with Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome Extension. It schould be possible afterwards to set a cookie for a domain which is not mine.

How is this possible with javascript?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: It would be easier for me, instead of opening the settings all the time.

Comment: Does anyone know why some web sites with specific URL like: "www.something.com" has cookies with another domain like: ".gstatic.com", "sth.com" and etc?

Comment: @MeirDayan That happens when a site includes assets such as JS from another domain, and those responses set cookies for those domains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a sample implementation for cookies, with this you can set cookies

[image]

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name" : "Cookie API Demo",
  "version" : "1",
  "description" : "This is demonstration of Cookie API",
  "permissions": [ "cookies","<all_urls>"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "screen.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.js***

```
function cookieinfo(){
    /*chrome.cookies.getAll({},function (cookie){
        console.log(cookie.length);
        for(i=0;i<cookie.length;i++){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie[i]));
        }
    });
    chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores(function (cookiestores){
        for(i=0;i<cookiestores.length;i++){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cookiestores[i]));
        }
    });*/
    chrome.cookies.set({"name":"Sample1","url":"http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html","value":"Dummy Data"},function (cookie){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
        console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    });
    /*chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function (changeInfo){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(changeInfo));
    });*/
}
window.onload=cookieinfo;
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if we set domain like: chrome.cookies.set({"name":"Sample1","url":"http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html","value":"Dummy Data", "domain": "sth.com"}); ? Note that, sth is different from chrome.com!